# Is it possible use the like command in queryover nHibernate? How can I do this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I want to search through parts of the record, not only in accurate records. In this exemple I search for the accurate records:

```
var v = NhSession.QueryOver<Dados.Models.PersonModel>()
            .Where(w=>w.Name == "Mary"))
            .List();
```

I can do this by queryover or only with criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the: `WhereRestrictionOn`. It could look like this

```
var v = NhSession
    .QueryOver<Dados.Models.PersonModel>()
    //.Where(w => w.Name == "Mary"))
    .WhereRestrictionOn(w => w.Name)
      .IsLike("Mary", MatchMode.Start);
    .List();
```

The `MatchMode` enum will decide where to put the '%' generated SQL Statement